# java.lang.ClassException: A cannot be cast into B

Tags: java, inheritance

I implemented this code:

```
class A {
    //some code
}
class B extends A {
    // some code
}

class C {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        B b1 = (B) new A();
        A a1 = (B) new A();
    }
}
```

Both of these lines, when compiled separately, compile fine,but give runtime error
with *`java.lang.ClassException: A cannot be cast into B`.*

Why they compile well, but give a runtime error?

Comment: Because an instance of `A` has nothing to do with `B`. And that's a runtime check.

Comment: Seriously, this is basic OOP. But looks like people don't care about it and prefer to post answers and upvote when this is widely explained in the net.

Comment: Consider the classic example: *Is dog an animal? **Yes**. Is animal a Dog? **Maybe**. But not always*. By the cast, you're telling the compiler to trust you that you're not going to do mistakes. But, in runtime, your program will crash since you're not really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Variables of type `A` can store references to objects of type `A` or its subtypes like in your case class `B`.

So it is possible to have code like:

```
A a = new B();
```

Variable `a` is of type `A` so it have only access to API of that class, it can't access methods added in class B which object it refers to. But sometimes we want to be able to access those methods so it should be possible to somehow store reference from `a` in some variable of more accurate type (here `B`) via which we would be able to access those additional methods from class B.
BUT HOW CAN WE DO THAT?

Lets try to achieve it this way:

```
B b = a;//WRONG!!! "Type mismatch" error
```

Such code gives compile time `Type mismatch` error. It happens to save us from situation like this:

- `class B1 extends A`
- `class B2 extends A`

  and we have `A a = new B1();`.

  Now lets try to assign `B1 b = a;`. Remember that **compiler doesn't know what actually is held under variable `a`** so it needs to generate code which will be safe for all possible values. If compiler wouldn't complain about `B1 b = a;` it should also allow to compile `B2 b = a;`. So just to be safe it doesn't let us do it.

  So what should we do to assign reference from `a` to `B1`? We need to *explicitly* tell compiler that we are aware of potential type mismatch issue here, but we are sure that reference held in `a` can be safely assigned in variable of type `B`. We do so by *casting* value from `a` to type `B` via `(B)a`.

  ```
  B b = (B)a;
  ```

---

But lets go back to example from your question

```
B b1 = (B) new A();
A a1 = (B) new A();
```

`new` operator returns reference of the same type as created object, so `new A()` returns reference of the type `A` so

```
B b1 = (B) new A();
```

can be seen as

```
A tmp = new A();
B b1 = (B) tmp;
```

Problem here is that **you can't store reference to object of superclass in variable of its derived type**.
Why such limitation exist? Lets say that derived class adds some new methods that supertype doesn't have like

```
class A {
    // some code
}

class B extends A {
    private int i;
    public void setI(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
}
```

If this would be allowed

```
B b = (B)new A();
```

you could later end up with invoking `b.setI(42);`. But will it be correct? No because instance of class A doesn't have method `setI` nor *field* `i` which that method uses.

So to prevent such situation `(B)new A();` at *runtime* throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 8):

The reason it fails at runtime is that the object isn't a B. It's an A. So while **some** As can be casts as Bs, yours cannot.

The compilier just can't analyze everything that happened to your A object. For example.

```
A a1 = new B();
A a2 = new A();

B b1 = (B) a1;    // Ok
B b2 = (B) a2;    // Fails
```

So the compilier isn't sure whether your A object is actually castable to a B. So in the above, it would think that the last 2 lines were ok. But when you actually run the program, it realizes that `a2` is not a B, it's only an A.

Answer (score 3):

when you say B extends A, A becomes father of B
now technically B has all charecteristics of A **plus its own**
while A has charecteristics of itself only

if you say convert A into B and assign to B, that is ok
but if you say cast A into B and assign to A, thats not possible as A here does not know **extra charecteristics present in B.**

and these things happens at runtime so it will give you a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

```
A a1 = (B) new A();
```

Because `A` is NOT `B`.

Compile time works because you are casting and explicitly guaranteeing compiler that you are sure at runtime `A` will be `B` .

Answer (score 2):

The name it self implies the `compiler` will just looks at compile-time type of the `expression`.

It does not do assumptions on the runtime type of the `expression`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

Coming to real problem

You **cannot** cast A to B.You **can** cast B to A.When you have a Mango,You have Fruit.But when you have a Fruit,It not mean that You have a Mango.

Answer (score 2):

When B extends A, it means all methods and properties of A are also present in B.

So you can ever cast B to A,

but you CANNOT cast A to B.

You have to be really care about casting in your application.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Think that when you are extending you have to use `is a`

```
B `is a` A
A `is not` B
```

A more realistic example

```
class Animal{
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

class Cat extends Animal{
}
```

A DOG `IS A` Animal
AN ANIMAL `IS NOT` a DOG necessary (Example : a cat is not a dog, and a cat is an animal)

You are getting `runtime exception` cause , in runtime realize that that animal is not a dog, this is call `downcasting` and is not safe what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the compile part, but I can explain the runtime error.

B extends A, which means that every object of class B, is also an object of type A. The other way around is not true.

Compare A with 'Mammal', and B with 'Cow'. A Cow is always a Mammal, but not every Mammal is a Cow.

Answer (score 1):

Has to do with when casting is done. You are telling the compiler: "Hey, don't worry about it, this is what I say it is, if you have a problem, take it up with me at runtime."

Basically, the compiler is letting you do your thing. When you explicitly cast something, the compiler doesn't do checks. When you run, and the program tries to cast but fails, that's when you will see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Because, all the compiler sees is that an A is cast into a B. Since some A's can actually be B's this may work for those A's. By writing the explicit cast, you ensure that this particular  A is actually a valid B. However, this is not the case.

```
A justA = new A();
A anAThatIsAlsoAValidB = new B(); // implicit cast to supertype

B b1 = (A) anAThatIsAlsoAValidB ; // Cast an A into a B. At runtime, this will work fine! Compiler allows casting A into B.
B b2 = (A) justA; // Cast an A into a B. At runtime, this won't work. Compiler has/uses no more info than above.
```

Here's why the compiler does not really know about the type:

```
com.example.ThridPartyType obj = new com.example.ThridPartyType();
B b = (B) obj.getSomeA(); 
// getSomeA() returns A and that is all the compiler knows.
// Depeding on the implementation of "ThridPartyType::getSomeA()" the A returned may or may not actually also be a valid B. 
// Hence, if the cast works or not will only be known at runtime. If it doesn't, the Exception is thrown.
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a compiletime casting -

```
A a = new B();
```

Such static castings are implicitly performed by the compiler, because the compiler is aware of the fact that B is-a A.

Following doesn't compile -

```
B b = new A();
```

No compiletime casting here because the compiler knows that A is not B.

Following compiles -

```
B b = (B) new A();
```

It is a dynamic casting. With `(B)` you are telling the compiler explicitly that you want the casting to happen at runtime. And you get a CCE at runtime, when the runtime tries to perform the cast but finds out that it cannot be done and throws a CCE.

When you do (or have to do) something like this, the responsibility falls upon you (not the compiler) to make sure that a CCE doesn't occur at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `B extends A` means that `B` *is* `A`, i.e. B is like A but probably add some other stuff.

The opposite is wrong. `A` *is not* `B`. Therefore you cannot cast `A` to `B`.

Think this way. `A` is `Animal`. `B` is `Bee`. Is `Bee` animal? Yes it is. Is any animal Bee? Not it is not. For example Dog is animal but definitely not a Bee.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `A` is a parent of `B`. `B` **extends** the functionality of the `A` but keeps the original functionality of `A`. So `B` can in fact be cast to `A`, but not vice versa.

What if `B` added a new method, let's say `newMethodInB()`. If you would try to call that method through variable `B` on the instance `A` (imagine that the cast worked) what would you expect? Well, you would definitely get an error because that method does not exist in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use BeanUtils.copyProperties(child, parent) for you target.

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35683833)